# Problem with library for quick Wasserstein distance calculation

Tags: python, pytorch, data-analysis

I need a tool to quickly calculate the Wasserstein distance between two two-dimensional point sets. I have been using Gudhi, but it appears to be too slow, and I need a faster alternative. I found the geomloss library, which appears to be fast enough, but the results differ, e.g.

```py
from gudhi.wasserstein import wasserstein_distance
import numpy as np

dgm1 = np.array([[2.7, 3.7],[9.6, 14.],[34.2, 34.974]])
dgm2 = np.array([[2.8, 4.45],[9.5, 14.1]])

wasserstein_distance(dgm1, dgm2, order=1)
```

yields `1.2369999999999965`, while

```py
import torch
from geomloss import SamplesLoss

I1 = torch.Tensor(dgm1)
I2 = torch.Tensor(dgm2)
I1.requires_grad_()

loss = SamplesLoss(loss='sinkhorn', debias=False, p=1, blur=1e-3, scaling=0.999, backend='auto')
loss(I1, I2)
```

yields `tensor(12.9882, grad_fn=<SelectBackward0>)`. I don't expect the two results to match perfectly, but ten-fold difference is a bit too much.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could help me with either forcing the geomloss to yield result similar to the gudhi, or finding any alternative (that gives result similar to the gudhi).

Comment: Just a comment that there are 2 implementations of wasserstein_distance in gudhi, one in gudhi.wasserstein and one in gudhi.hera. Of course neither is nearly as fast as what you can get with ideas similar to geomloss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got comments from the developers on GitHub (please, see [this issue](https://github.com/jeanfeydy/geomloss/issues/71) for more information). Here is a short summary:

- what `gudhi` calls `wasserstein` is not the same as what `geomloss` calls `Wasserstein`, it seems to be discrepancy between OT and TDA communities terminology;
- `gudhi` computes a non-standard variation ([documented here](https://gudhi.inria.fr/python/latest/wasserstein_distance_user.html#optimal-transport)) that is specifically tailored for persistence diagrams;
- currently there is no `gudhi` version of `wasserstein` implemented in `geomloss` but it may be possible to see it in the future.

Comment: IIRC there is at least one set of parameters (order=1 and internal_p=2?) where, if you append to dgm1 the symmetric of dgm2 and vice versa, you can get geomloss (with the right options) to compute essentially (ignoring the relaxation) the same quantity as gudhi (up to some factor 2, square root, or whatever). Although I don't think I ever tried it...